# Convert associative array to indexed array with associative subarrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have a simple associative array with country data like this:

```
$array = array('country1' => CountryOne, 'country2' => Country Two);
```

How can I *dynamically* transform this array in a multiple array like:

```
array(2) {
    [0] =>  array(2) {
        ["code"] => "country1", ["name"] => "CountryOne"
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
        ["code"] => "country2", ["name"] => "CountryTwo"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply [loop](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) through it and create a new array from each key/value pair.

```
<?php
    $array = array("country1" => "CountryOne", "country2" => "CountryTwo");

    $newArray = array();

    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        array_push($newArray, array("code" => $key, "name" => $value));
    }

    var_dump($newArray);
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Iterate through your array and fill another with what you find in it :

```
$dst_array = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
    $dst_array[] = array('code' => $k, 'name' => $v);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreach is the obvious way, but we can use the functional way too:

```php
$input = array('country1' => 'CountryOne', 'country2' => 'Country Two');

$output = array_map(function($each) {
  return array(
    'code' => key($each),
    'name' => current($each));
  }, array_chunk($input, 1, true));

print_r($input);
print_r($output);
```

We split the associative array in chunks of 1 element and we get an array of subarrays by each key-value pair. After, we can apply a map function to adapt each pair to our needs.

Example: https://3v4l.org/9Xg6t#v8.1.4

Answer (score -2):

This is simple do like this

```
$array = array( array('code'=> "country1", 'name'=> "CountryOne"), array('code'=> "country2", 'name'=> "CountryTwo"));
```

Comment: From the question is implied that he like to do it dynamically. It is obvious he already knew how to do this.

Comment: @GillesLesire--ok